# Solve the integral with complex number and floor function.

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis

let $z\in\mathbb{C},\,0<\left|z\right|<1$.I would like to calculate the integral $$\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{\left(1-z\right)^{\left\lfloor t\right\rfloor }}{t^{2}}dt$$ where ${\left\lfloor t\right\rfloor }$ is the floor function. I've tried the residue theorem but I haven't found a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have:
$$\int_{n}^{n+1}\frac{(1-z)^n}{t^2}\,dt = \frac{(1-z)^n}{n(n+1)}$$
hence:
$$\int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{(1-z)^{\lfloor t\rfloor}}{t^2}\,dt = \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(1-z)^n}{n(n+1)}=1+\frac{z}{1-z}\log z.$$